# User agent - ADG

Tags: request, user-agent

Can anyone tell what the browser is for the below User agent? Never heard of ADG, any leads to that would be really helpful.

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 ADG/11.0.3208 Safari/537.36

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response

most likely it is `AOL Desktop`.

we have such a useragent in matomo-org/device-detector

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 ADG/11.0.2617 AOLBUILD/11.0.2617 Safari/537.36
```